# $lookup search Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

### Objective

To have an efficient search using references in MongoDB.

### Background

I have a Smoothie DB on Mongo. A smoothie is an object with a reference to a Food object and it is represented like:

```
{
    name: "Red Velvet Cake",
    ingredients: [{
        food_id: "strawberry_raw",
        //other really cool fields
    },
    //other ingredients
    ],
    preparation: "Mix everything and have fun!",
    Source: "Super Smoothies, p. 142"
}
```

Now, a Food object is represented by the following example:

```
{
    "_id": "strawberry_raw",
    "name": "strawberries",
    //other really cool fields
}
```

### Problem

With these schemas in mind, I am making sure that a Smoothie object knows all the Food objects that build it. Since each Smoothie object will have at most 6 or 7 food objects, I believe this is the best choice as it follows the [MongoDB's Principle of least Cardinality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkaRuEUtTEw).

However, now I want to allow the following functionalities:

1. Given a list of ingredient names, return all smoothies that contain at least one of those ingredients
2. Given a list of ingredient names, return only the smoothies that contain **all** those ingredients.

And I have no idea how to do it with MongdoDB.

### Example

The following examples illustrate what I want.

Imagine I have the following Foods:

```
let foods = [{
        "_id": "strawberry_raw",
        "name": "strawberries"
    }, {
        "_id": "honeydew_melon_raw",
        "name": "honeydew melon"
    }, {
        "_id": "coconut_milk",
        "name": "homemade coconut milk"
    }];
```

And the following Smoothies:

```
let smoothies = [
{
    name: "Coco Berry",
    ingredients: [
        { food_id: "strawberry_raw" }, 
        { food_id: "coconut_milk"}
    ],
    preparation: "Mix everything and have fun!",
    Source: "Super Smoothies, p. 142"
}, 
{
    name: "Tropical Melon",
    ingredients: [
        { food_id: "honeydew_melon_raw"},
        { food_id: "coconut_milk"}
    ],
    preparation: "Mix everything and have fun!",
    Source: "Super Smoothies, p. 51"
}];
```

Given a search with the term "coconuts, strawberry", the functionalities would return:

1. Coco Berry and Tropical Melon, as both smoothie have at least one of the ingredients (coconut milk)
2. Coco Berry, as this smoothie has both ingredients, and the second one is missing one ingredient.

### What I tried and what i need

I know that to turn a search like "coconuts" return a Food with name "Coconut Milk" I have to index the names in the Food collection, which I did.

I also searched and I found that I will likely need to use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), however, I don't know how to move from that point forward. How do I do it ?

Comment: I am reading https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction but so for it is quite complex...

Comment: I was forced to use mongo for 1 year until they listened to me and we switched to a relational database (which was the fuking obvious thing since our data is relational). You can either store the whole ingredients inside the Smoothies (that is, store the whole ingredient object) or make some crap to do this fake joins. The first option has the trouble that if you update an ingredient you have to update it everywhere. The second option has the trouble that the more complex your relationship gets, the harder and messier it gets.

Comment: By the way, if you store the whole ingredients in the Smoothies, you can then search inside that "ingredients" array easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need of adding a join or index you can use $regex,let me try my hand,consider smothie as your collection
`

```
db.collection.find({ingredients : {$elemMatch : {$or :[
{food_id : {$regex : "coconuts")},{food_id : {$regex : "strawberry")}]}}})
```

`

Your second query 
`

```
db.collection.find({ingredients : {$elemMatch : {$and :[
{food_id : {$regex : "coconuts")},{food_id : {$regex : "strawberry")}]}}})
```

`